# Where is memory allocated for member function when we create an object of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, memory

I was just wondering how is the memory allocated when we create an object of particular class in C++, that has 100s of data members and 10000s of member functions.

Do each time we create an object we allocate memory for data members and member functions or only the memory for data members gets created?

Suppose I have a class:

```
class A {
   int a,b,c,d,e; // ...many more variables;
   // ........
   // ........
   // 100 more variables
public:
    int getID(){ return a; }
    int perFormSomething(){ return  b; }
    // ..............
    // ..............
    // 1000 more functions;  
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A[10000]; // array of objects of A
    return 0;
}
```

If member functions are getting memory as well then I think it will cause a huge memory burden to the operating system?

Comment: look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888069/memory-allocation-for-member-functions-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the execution of a program, instructions need to be load in memory, but due to the code of each member function is shared between instances, there is no *per-instance* allocation.

With member variables the opposite occurs, they need to be load *per-instance* because each instance has its own values for those variables. So, when a new instance is created **during execution**, it's allocated in the memory.

Comment: Thanks @alseether for the explanation But What I wanted to know is where actually the function definitions are stored ?

Comment: @ChandraShekharRam Then you should have said so. In your question. You didn't.

Comment: The functions are transformed into assembly code when compiling. They don't need real storage beacuse **they are the code**. It can be seen as stored into the code itself.
When you call a function in your code, the compiler creates a `jump` instruction to that section of the code, where the function code is placed

Comment: @alseether What a load of waffle. Of course they need 'space in memory' and 'storage'. What they don't need is *per-instance* storage, because they don't vary per instance.

Comment: @EJP That's true. Before executing the program, the instructions need to be loaded in memory. I understood the question more like *What happens when an object is created?* during the executiong. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: So fix your answer.

Comment: http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus09.html

Comment: Unless you count the virtual function table as "member variable" (debatable) or padding/alignment as part of "member variables", your first crossed-out statement is straight up false. I get that you struck it through, but I don't think you should keep it at all.